# log4net logging find method name

Tags: log4net, log4net-appender

I am logging log using log4net in an ActionMethod whose name is LogHandlerMethod(). That ActionMethod is called inside different functions(Actions). How to get methodname of those functions inside which LogHandlerMethod() has been called

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a CallerMemberNameAttribute:

```
public void LogHandlerMethod(... my parameters ... ,[CallerMemberName]string memberName = "")
{
    //memberName will contain name of calling method
```

Call this without the adding the memberName parameter (the memberName  will be filled by the CallerMemberNameAtribute)

Comment: Do I need to pass in function as argument. What if I want to access in code?

Comment: The CallerMemberNameAttribute takes care of setting the name of the caller function. Do not pass the memberName as parameter in your caller function.

Comment: I have to make comparison in webconfig files. Say if this method has been been from particular action do something otherwise do something else.